# Visual Studio breakpoint unable to be hit

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to set a breakpoint on the setter of a property.  The property looks like:

```
var _selectedViewModel;

public MyViewModel SelectedViewModel
{
  get
  {
    return _selectedViewModel;
  }
  set
  {
    _selectedViewModel= value;
    Name = _selectedViewModel.Name;
  }
}
```

When I try to set a breakpoint on "Name = ..." VS fails to set it with this error:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is
> associated with this line. Possible causes include: conditional
> compilation or complier optimizations, or the target architecture of
> this line is not supported by the current debugger code type.

The strange thing is I can set a breakpoint fine on the getter and it is hit as expected.

I tried cleaning/rebuilding but that didn't help.  The solution configuration is set to Debug / Any CPU. "Suppress JIT on module load" is enabled.  Even tried restarting the PC hoping that would help but it did not.

Any ideas as to how to get the breakpoint to work here?

Comment: Also, check if optimization is not turned on on Build tab of project settings.

Comment: Even i thought the same

Comment: @SimonDugré Yeah, restarting VS was the first thing I tried but it didn't help.  Rebuilding made no difference and I am debugging the right project.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Had a look and "Optimize Code" is unchecked for the project.

Comment: check also  if  the vs is in debug mode and not in release.

Comment: Try also to disable the "Just My Code" option in the Debug/General settings.

Comment: The optimizer ignores that line! `Name = _selectedViewModel.Name;` --> equals to
`this.Name = _selectedViewModel.Name;`  --> equals to `_selectedViewModel.Name = _selectedViewModel.Name;` because `this` uses the getter what returns _selectedViewModel - so the same --> useless code - AFAIK. We cannot set a breakpoint on a line that does not create any code. Just place that breakpoint a line above.

Comment: @dimmits Yeah, the configuration is Debug and the platform is Any CPU

Comment: @Xyloto Tried disabling Just My Code but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @BitLauncher: you sure? Name = ... is this. Name = ... which means the code seems to set the name property when model is set.

Comment: @BitLauncher Name here is a property of the class that contains the SelectedViewModel property.  "this" is not the same as the _selectedViewModel.  Also, I cannot even set a breakpoint on the line above.  VS does not even set it.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla Yes, `_selectedViewModel` is of type  `MyViewModel `, otherwise the getter would create a compile error. So in the setter it sets the value to  _selectedViewModel, and in the next line it takes  `this.Name = _selectedViewModel.Name` - and `this` is going through the getter and returning `_selectedViewModel` again. So finally the line is `/* name = this.Name ---> this.getter returning _selectedViewModel */ _selectedViewModel.Name = _selectedViewModel.Name;`

Comment: @Flack @Wiktor Zychla You are right. I thought it over: My idea could be right if there is another property in that class: `public <NameType> Name { get { return _selectedViewModel.Name; } set { _selectedViewModel.Name = value; }` or other similarly weard code, perhaps more nested/hidden making a circular reference? Check perhaps base classes too for such stuff. Is it that reason?